# Viewing large image size using BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, image

I currently have an image that I load into program as a BufferedImage. This BufferedImage is put inside a JPanel class which has a fixed size.

Now the problem I am facing is that how can I pan this large BufferedImage inside this fixed size JPanel.

The JPanel dimension is definitely smaller than the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, attach some scroll bars to the JPanel (south and east, using a `BorderLayout`) that will be visible only if the image is too large and/or high. Attach another `JPanel` in the remaining space (center). In that inner `JPanel`, you would override the `paintComponent` method and would draw the portion of your `BufferedImage` into the `JPanel`. Use the scroll bars' offset to offset your image, and the inner `JPanel` for the width and height to draw (the viewport).

**Note:** your scroll bars will invoke the `repaint` method of your inner `JPanel` whenever their value change.

The `paintComponent` will be called by the system automatically (or manually) whenever the image needs to be redrawn. Doing this, you will be able to customize the view you give your image (if such feature is needed); rotation, scaling, pixel manipulation, custom overlays etc.

You can also attach some [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to the inner `JPanel` and modify the scroll bars' offset according the mouse movements (modifying the scroll bars will automatically trigger the repaint on the image) for mouse interaction with your component. Just a thought.

Comment: You may alo want to set te preferred (& possibly te minimum) size of the panel hosting the image to the same dimensions of the image. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html for an example

Comment: not necessarily. You only need an `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. These values will always be available when the `paintComponent` method is invoked and define the visible portion of the image to draw.

Comment: But you might like to suggest to the layou manager what size the panel is, based on the size of the image, unless you want to scale the image based on the parent container. You should only ever require the width & hight, the x,y should be taken care of by he viewport

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the question, the image *is* larger than the `JPanel` and the image should pan, not be resized, neither is the `JPanel` should be resized. The question is about how to pan a large image inside a small view area.

Comment: No, the resize (or lack of) I got, the fixed size pane is what I missed. Thought you were describing a scroll pane, but you were constructing our own

Comment: yeah :) `JScrollPane` would be good only if the inner `JPanel` is as big as the image, which is a waste of memory.